# Using Docker for Asp.Net 5.0 Development on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core

I can succesully install and run an ASP.Net MVC application https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/dev/samples/1.0.0-beta4/HelloMvc on docker using:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "." "kestrel"]
```

Build

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

Run

```
docker run -t -d -p 80:5004 myapp
```

The Buildstep takes 2minutes, thats why I don't want to to run all the steps when I changed some files during development. What workflow would I use when developing for a runtime that is hosted in docker? Or is docker not the right environment for development?

**EDIT**
I copied all files of the application including the dockerfile to "/dev_app" changed to that directory and run

```
  $ docker run -v /dev_app:/app -d -p 80:5004 myapp
```

The output is the id of the container

```
docker ps
```

Does not show any entries. Is there still something missing?

**EDIT 2**

executing

```
docker log [myid]
```

returns

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project 'app' from /app
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ApplicationHostContext..ctor (IServiceProvider serviceProvider, System.String projectDirectory, System.String packagesDirectory, System.String configuration, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName targetFramework, ICache cache, ICacheContextAccessor cacheContextAccessor, INamedCacheDependencyProvider namedCacheDependencyProvider, IAssemblyLoadContextFactory loadContextFactory, Boolean skipLockFileValidation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost.Initialize (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHostOptions options, IServiceProvider hostServices) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost..ctor (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHostOptions options, IServiceProvider hostServices) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 1):

During development, put the code in a directory on host and mount that into the container, over the top of the existing code. For example, if you put a copy of the code in `dev_app` in your current directory:

```
$ docker run -v $(pwd)/dev_app:/app -d -p 80:5004 myapp
```

Any changes to the code in the `dev_app` directory will be reflected immediately in the container. When you've finished making changes, you can rebuild the container with the new version of the code for distribution.

Comment: That sounds good.But I was still not sucesfull. Please check the edited question.

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner. That's a completely different question now. The number is the ID of the container. If you run `docker logs ID` it should tell you what happened. If you still have problems, open a new question.